# Loading data from the database to nav-bar. JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wanna load the data from the my database when my main page is loading. I would like show the list of my process in nav-bar but below script doesn't work.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zvququ1L/)

```
   $('#filtrM li a').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllProcess", "Home")',
                    data: "",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            $('.nav nav-sidebar ul').append(
                                $('<li>').append(
                                $('<a>').attr('href', val.IDprocess).append(
                                $('<span>').attr('class', 'tab').append(val.NameProcess)
                                                                                        )));
                        });

                    },
                });
            });
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle of your code

Comment: Ok, I added link to JSFIDDLE.

Comment: Please explain what does not work.  Have you checked the console in your browser?

Comment: It should add the list process to my .nav nav-sidebar but it doesn't. It enters to the method GetAllProcess and get correctly all processes but after it doesnt set my data to the .nav nab-sidebar.

Comment: Please check your console the actual call that you make is call or not.